# Is there any way to generate Passport token on user login via web middleware?

Tags: laravel

I want to upload images via `Vue2Dropzone` package in my Laravel project but it keep throwing `401 Unauthorized` error. The `auth:api` middleware works fine when the request is sent from `axios`. The package itself uses plain javascript to make a request.

I think I just need to pass the token via `Vue2Dropzone's sending` method but when I checked the database, the passport table was empty. I need to login via API route to generate its token but my project is a Multi Page Application and it doesn't do a user authentication via API at all. Instead, user is logged in via it's built in authentication on `web` routes.

Is there any way to generate passport token when a user logged in via `web` middleware without modifying its built in login controller? I need it to be like that so I can pass it to my Vue `props` like this in my blade file:

```
<my-component user-token="{{ Auth::user()->passportToken }}"></my-component>
```

Or maybe there is another solution for this problem? Please let me know.

Comment: I've always approached this differently. I use Dropzone to generate a data uri for the image and then append this to the form object used by axios. I can then do what I want with the data uri on the server side and don't have to worry about integrating Dropzone into my auth flow.

Comment: could you please post an example of it as the answer sir? I can't imagine how it's to be.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `X-CSRF-TOKEN` on the header.

```
data() {
  return {
    dropzoneOptions: {
      url: '/api/v1/productImageUploads',
      thumbnailWidth: 150,
      maxFilesize: 0.5,
      thumbnailWidth: 200,
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content
      }
    }
  }
},
```